# Inserting variable values into variable columns in C#/MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

My issue is that I import any kind of excel file which leads to a random amount of Columns and therefor values stores in these columns.

This is my string to  `ExecuteNonQuery` it;

```
    getAllValuesString = "INSERT INTO " + dbName + " (" + addHeader + " ) VALUES ('" + addValue + "')";
```

dbName is just the table name -> irrelevant right now
addHeader are the column names all in one string => `"Column1 , Column 2"`
addValue is one string for all the values  => `"@value1 , @value2"`

Now of course when I do =>

```
    cmdAddRow.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addValue", addValue);
```

then I only have 1 value added but 2 columns and it won't work.
I'm looking for the right format to AddWithValue all values of the addValue string no matter how many there are but I haven't found the right format yet. I tried to weave in an array and add it like that but with no success.

I'm trying to do this without Bulkadding the whole thing - any ideas?

Comment: Loose the single quotes in values()

Comment: You don't need the single quote when using parametrized queries

Comment: Thanks that was part of the problem. The other part was me putting the AddWithValue in a loop where it shouldn't be